# How to map url parameter to some other filter field in Django DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have in **views.py**:

```
class XYZAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = ABCModel.objects
    serializer_class = ABCModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('field_1',)
```

In url, `GET` parameter will come as `X` which is field in related table to model `ABCModel` through `field_2`. I don't want my url parameter to be as **field_2__X**, i just want it as **X**, is there any way through any generic approach or any solution using **filters.py** ? How to map url parameter with some other parameter in filter in proper manner?

Answer (score 2):

In **filters.py**:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from my_app.models import ABCModel


class XYZFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    X = filters.CharFilter(field_name='field_2__X', lookup_expr='exact')
    # In place of CharFilter, you can use your preferred filter type

    class Meta:
        model = ABCModel
        fields = ['field_1', 'X']
```

In **views.py**:

```
class FormFieldAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = ABCModel.objects
    serializer_class = ABCModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = XYZFilter
```

Note: in **views**, `filter_class` is used instead of `filterset_class` (which is specified in docs). The latter was not working in my case. If someone has any explanation for it's behaviour, add it on to this post.

For more info, refer to [Django-Filters Documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html)

Comment: If `filterset_class` is not working for you, you are most likely using django-filter 1.1 or earlier. `filter_class` was renamed to `filterset_class` in 2.x

Comment: @sherpa You can add it to the answer, with proper reference.